# Self declare an object to insert into NoSQL DB

Tags: c#, json, object, xamarin, nosql

I have 4 variables to put into an object and then I will be using `JsonConvert.Serialize` to serialize them into Json format.

However, I tried doing with one variable only

```
var sampleinfo = [{"Name": "name"}];
```

It doesn't work and kept prompting `} expected` . May I know why?

The other 3 variables I have are `ID`, `Notes` and `Done`.

I have tried doing all 4 at one go with the same code as above but same error prompted.

Comment: `[` and `]` are used to represent collection in json. So if it's a simple object then json should start with `{` and end with `}`

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya I have tried doing with just `{` and `}`. However it will prompt error that regarding array initialize.

Comment: There is a typo: `"Name": name"`

Comment: @SushiHangover Sorry, fixed that typo. Doesn't work even if without the typo

Comment: Are you trying to insert into MongoDb database?

Comment: @Vaibhavshetty Firebase, through RESTful service